# Dynamic DNS, connect subdomain to internal NAS and laptop

Tags: dynamic-dns

I'm trying to setup the following at home.

1. File server via my Western Digital MyBook Live 2TB (NAS) via Ethernet
2. Active Server via my laptop which will be online 24/7 via Ethernet (wireless)

I have a Thomson TG784 router/modem.

Let's say my external IP is: 84.66.66.66
Internal IP Laptop: 192.168.0.60
Internal IP MyBook Live (NAS): 192.168.0.61

My domain name I own on an external website is:
laptop.mydomain.com
mybook.mydomain.com

How would fix this, so I can connect the domain names to my internal IP's and access them, whenever, wherever I have internet access no matter what computer/system/OS I am on?

I do not have a static IP via my ISP, so I'm guessing I have to use a service such as dyndns.org etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Setup Dynamic DNS account.**

no-ip.com will do as well as anything listed in this (my) [biased list](http://talkdns.info/list).

The disadvantage of no-ip.com and like is that for free account you get address in the form of yoursomething.no-ip.com. You can of course setup laptop.mydomain.com as CNAME to yoursomething.no-ip.com, but to me it seems "ugly" way. It would be best to use Dynamic DNS provider that will host dynamic DNS for YOUR domain (see the list above).

**2. Configure Dynamic DNS client.**

You will need client-side software to update you dynamic DNS whenever your IP changes. You have two choices: 1. update dynamic DNS from your TG784 (it does support dynamic DNS) and 2. Install Dynamic DNS client on your laptop. You can update both records from one place since they both point to the same IP, or you can setup one of the records as CNAME to another one or even use single wildcard record (if your DNS provider supports it), or as Ronald suggested use one dynamic DNS record and CNAME both hostnames to it.

**3. Setup port forwarding**
  On your router you have to forward some ports to NAS and some to your laptop. If both devices must use same port (like port 80), things become more complicated and I'd just avoid it.

**4. Open firewall**

On the laptop and NAS, open relevant ports in the firewall (if there is one).

Comment: Or try my baby: http://www.net-me.net (BETA started today).

Comment: I would advice transferring your domain to the dyndns provider instead of using multiple providers, you'll get a more reliable result. and if your router or nas supports it, use the build in dyndns client instead of using your laptop, that way if you're away (with your laptop) you can still reach your nas after an ip change.

Comment: @s4uadmin I agree. If some DNS provider supported by your router can host your domain, go for it. Maybe even it worth paying to save the hassle of laptop client (which will never be as good as router client). Alternatively, maybe it's worth installing dd-wrt on the router.

Answer (score 0):

The way you could get this to work is:

1. Use dyndns to map your dynamic ip from your ISP to a domainname provided by dyndns
2. Change your DNS for "mydomain.com", map subdomain.mydomain.com to dynamic.dyndns.org with cname
3. Map the specific external port to you internal ip in your router.